# Taking out a column of a Multi-Dimmensional Array and sorting it?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have a good-sized multi-dimmensioanl array:

```
listPatients =   
[[  "Johnson",   "Fred", "N", "2763 Filibuster Drive",  "Lakeland", "FL", "37643", "Q", "05/27/1935", "164-55-0726", "N"]] \
+                
[[ "Williams",  "Betty", "L",    "701 Collage Avenue",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "F", "11/27/1971", "948-44-1038", "Y"]] \
+                
[[     "Ling", "Hector", "X",     "1500 Raceway Lane",     "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "10/17/2003", "193-74-0274", "Y"]] \
+ 
[[    "Albin",   "Ross", "L",      "207 Daisy Avenue",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "12/08/1990", "458-57-2867", "N"]] \
+                
[[ "Anderson",  "Jason", "O",       "1527 Lewis Road",     "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "11/25/1991", "093-50-1093", "Y"]] \
+                
[[     "Baca",  "Edwin", "L",       "25 Hunters Lane",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "10/30/1992", "159-56-9731", "Y"]] \
+                
[[   "Birner", "Dalton", "M",     "851 Applebe Court",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "09/22/1993", "695-21-2340", "Y"]] \
+                
[["Dominguez", "Javier", "B",   "1410 Waterford Blvd",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "08/04/1994", "753-66-6482", "N"]] \
+                
[[   "Aimino", "Nicolo", "S",      "2379 Runners Way",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "07/11/1995", "852-73-4196", "Y"]] \
+                
[["Armstrong","Addison", "T",    "46 Hawthorne Drive",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "06/18/1996", "648-81-1456", "Y"]] \
+                
[[    "Beard",    "Ian", "J",  "1814 Constitution Ct",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "05/28/1997", "879-61-1829", "N"]] \
+                
[[ "Calderon",  "Yamil", "C",         "345 Cigar Row",     "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "04/07/1998", "123-87-6431", "Y"]] \
+                
[[   "Carter", "Thomas", "P",       "896 Pine Avenue",     "Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "03/12/1999", "248-65-3197", "Y"]] \
+                
[[  "Chaname",  "Bryan", "D",    "24 Blue Belt Drive",  "Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "02/23/2000", "741-85-9632", "Y"]] \
+                
[[   "Chaney", "Chaney", "Z",    "2589 College Court",   "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "01/15/2001", "963-25-7418", "Y"]]
```

What I need to do is take out the [7]th element of each list and print it out all simultaneously. NOTE: I cannot use numPY.

Comment: post the actual list without + symbol.

Comment: is this a two-dimensional array?

Comment: What about the sorting part of the question?  Are you trying to sort the elements of the array by the 7th column?

Comment: what is the `+` between the lines?

Comment: @deadcode I am trying to extrapolate the 7th column of each list I have

Comment: @Marcin - the + is just appending the elements of the array - the end result of [[a,b]] + [[c,d]] is [ [a,b], [c,d] ]

Comment: @JoshuaPilkin - great - then the answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for patient in listPatients:
    print patient[6]
```

Or:

```
output = ""
for patient in listPatients:
    output += patient[6] + ", "
print output
```